# Find total number of sequences of black and white balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a box **$K$** white and **$K$** black balls. We build a sequence with next rules for each step:

1. if we selected a white ball, then we add it to the sequence
2. if we selected a black ball, then we add it to the sequence, select   another one and add it too

Find total number of such possible sequences after $K$ steps. With probabilities method I get next result: $$\binom{2K}{K}$$
Does exist a way to count it combinatorially? (not sure is it correct answer or not)

Comment: Suppose the first ball you select is W. So the sequence starts W. Do you stop at that point? If not, then there seems to be no difference between cases 1 and 2. You just keep adding balls until you have a sequence length 2K.

Comment: @almagest oh Sorry I forgot to add condition that we make K steps. Is it clear now? So length in range [K .. 2K]

Comment: Suppose you pick successively: W, B, W, B, B, W. How many steps is that? Is it four steps? ie first step W (type 1), second step B,W (type 2), third step B,B (type 2), fourth step W (type 1)?

Comment: @almagest exactly!

Comment: I only count 17 for K=3.

Comment: Enumeration via code gives $N=\{2,6,17,50,147,435,1290,\dots\}$ which has a close match in OEIS with [A027914](https://oeis.org/A027914)

Comment: @almagest the same, it mean that result is incorrect(

Comment: @almagest As I understand it, such sequences are not equally probable?